# How to add commands to before_script inherited from template

Tags: continuous-integration, yaml, gitlab-ci

Let's say I have a template which contains something like this:

```
.some-scripts: &some-scripts |
    set -e

    function somefunction() {
       
    }

.template-job:
  before_script:
    - *some-scripts
    - echo "Example command"
    - somefunction

build-job:
  extends: .template-job
  stage: build
  script: 
    - mvn build
```

This template is included in another gitlab-ci.yml and I am looking to add some specific commands to the before_script of my build-job without overriding the before_script of the template-job. Is it possible and how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found what I was looking for, I needed to use a [reference tag](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#reference-tags).

Here's what I came up with:

```
build-job:
  stage: build
  before_script: 
    - !reference [.template-job, before_script]
    - mycommand
    - mysecondcommand
  script: 
    - mvn build
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you cannot extend a `before_script`, just overwrite it. But there is an open [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/258606) regarding the extending behavior.

As a workaround you could just add the additional commands to your `script` section as `before_script`, `script` and `after_script` are ultimatley merged together to one block on execution.

```
.template-job:
  before_script:
    - echo "Example command"
    - echo "Second command"

build-job:
  extends: .template-job
  stage: build
  script: 
    - echo "third command"
    - echo "fourth command"
    - mvn build
```